# Comparing denoising algorithms performances using PSNR when there is no clean image (Ground Truth)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, noise-reduction

I have medical images containing speckle noises, and one of my tasks is to denoise these images. I tried 8 algorithms and inspected the denoised images visually.

I want to use PSNR to quantify the process. Based on the PSNR definition, it is calculated between noisy and clean (without any noises) images.

I there any way to quantify the denoising process performance without having clean images?